# VBA Collections: Only Adding a Select Amount of Values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, collections, counter

```
Dim item As New Collection 'collection will have numbers, the amount of which can change


For x = 1 To item(count)
      counter = counter + x
Next x
```

Is there anyway of getting only the select amount of values from a collection and adding them to a counter? Or do I have to use an array, as I'd rather use a collection

Comment: Are you asking for ```item.count```? Or you want the loop to be until some value stored as an item in your collection?

Comment: You need to explain your question in a little more detail. You have a collection of numeric values, and you want to return a count of specific values? As in, how many times is the number 7 in your collection? or maybe how many numbers greater than 0? What are you trying to count

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, the following will add the selected number of items:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim item As Collection
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim SelectedCount As Integer
   Dim counter As Integer
   
   Set item = New Collection
   item.Add 1
   item.Add 2
   item.Add 3
   
   SelectedCount = 2
   
   For x = 1 To SelectedCount
      counter = counter + item(x)
   Next
   
   MsgBox counter
End Sub
```

You will want to make sure `x` is a valid index.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your collection and count any number of things, like the example below:

```
Dim item As New Collection 'collection will have numbers, the amount of which can change
Dim lCount7 As Long
Dim lCountPos As Long
Dim counter As Long

Dim vItem As Variant

For Each vItem In item
    If vItem = 7 Then lCount7 = lCount7 + 1 'Total count of the number "7" in the collection
    If vItem > 0 Then lCountPos = lCountPos + 1 'Total count of positive values in the collection
Next
counter = item.Count 'Total numbers in the collection
```